# Turn Off the Folder/Namespace Convention

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, directory

I see people talking about the annoyance of [Visual Studio automatically creating a namespace to correspond with project folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289425/should-i-stop-fighting-visual-studios-default-namespace-naming-convention).  Is there a way to turn this off in VS 2010, without resorting to modifying class templates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use Resharper, there is an attribute on the folder 'Namespace Provider'.

[image]

Even if you set it to false, Visual Studio will still add folder name as a namespace. However, Resharper fixes it with one click on the namespace.

Comment: This answer doesn't address how to turn the convention off, it only tells how to make a specific folder not a provider.

Answer (score 2):

Use Resharper.  Turn off the "Namespace Provider" option and you should be good to go without modifying class templates.