# Visual Studio automatically adjusting namespace on designer files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, namespaces, strongly-typed-dataset

When ever I make a change to a typed-dataset in visual studio it will change the namespace to one based on what folder the file is in.  Is there anyway to stop if from changing the namespace if one is already defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn Off the Folder/Namespace Convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246637/turn-off-the-folder-namespace-convention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you've found an answer by now (possibly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246637/turn-off-the-folder-namespace-convention)) or accepted that [it's not really a bad way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289425/should-i-stop-fighting-visual-studios-default-namespace-naming-convention), but for those who run across this in the future:

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has a setting that allows you to do so - although it [sounds imperfect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246637/turn-off-the-folder-namespace-convention) to me.

Comment: I am tempted to flag this as a duplicate of that answer...  But for now ill give you credit for the answer.  No I had not solved it we just worked around it.