# Is it possible to modify page's namespace default value?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

When I create a new page in my ASP.NET application I have This code automatically generated:

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Rh_Acceuil.aspx.cs" Inherits="PAGODE.RESSHUM.Rh_Acceuil" %>
```

It's really usefull! But the inherits tag is made with project's directories (the file is in de RESSHUM directory)
but I prefer to delete this part and have this:

```
...Inherits="PAGODE.Rh_Acceuil ...
```

But I have to do that manually each time..

So, is it possible to set an option with the aim of Visual Studio don't care about directories when he make this nameSpace?

Thanks for response..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I've found a solution to do that without *resharper* (I'm sure it's a useful tool but expensive)

So, I just discover Item templates in Visual Studio, magic tool with which you can customize the way Visual studio make the files when you want a new item (.cs, .aspx, ...)

And in the templates you can put some values like $name$ or $itemname$ those values are replaced when file is generated.. (here by the name of windows user, and name of the file created)

I just  make a file .aspx with all the things I want and for the namespace I just set

```
Inherits=$itemname$
```

and the namespace is just the file name in this case..

Thanks for help!..

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar thread here:

[How to NOT include Visual Studio Project folder names in generated namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503908/how-to-not-include-visual-studio-solution-folder-names-in-generated-namespaces)

Looks like you would need [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which is not free for standard developers.

Another option, although perhaps as tedious, is to add new pages in the main project then move them to the appropriate sub folder.  At least then you wouldn't have to change the namespace in the aspx page and the code-behind.

Comment: Ok, but i'm sure it is possible without Resharper. (It wil be :-( )

Comment: @bAN: I wouldn't be so sure.  If Visual Studio didn't include that functionality, then I don't see how you can be `sure it is possible`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a work around that may help at least a little.

Comment: @bAN: So my **If** was wrong and it was possible... :)  I guess item templates are a logical place to do that.